# Singly linked list, why is the list empty (head == NULL)?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I created a singly linked list:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

bool isEmpty(Node *head){
    if (head == NULL){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

void append(Node *head, Node *last, int data){
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    if (isEmpty(head)){
        head = newNode;
        last= newNode;
    }
    else{
        last->next = newNode;
        last= newNode;
    }

}

void printList(Node *current){
    if (isEmpty(current)){
        cout << "List is empty." << endl;
    }
    else{
        int i = 1;
        while (current != NULL){
            cout << i << ". Node: " << endl;
            cout << current->data << endl;
            current = current->next;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void main(){
    Node *head = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;
    append(head, last, 53);
    append(head, last, 5512);
    append(head, last, 13);
    append(head, last, 522);
    append(head, last, 55);
    printList(head);
}
```

When I compile it, the output is this:

> List is empty.

But I don't know why. "head" gets an address, so "head" shouldn't be NULL. But apparently it is NULL.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: You've tagged C++11: start using `nullptr` in place of `NULL`.

Comment: `void append(Node*& head, Node*& last, int data)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that arguments to functions are by default passed by value, which means that the arguments value is *copied* and the function only works on the copy and not the original.

Now take the `append` function, when you pass the `head` argument the pointer is copied into the argument, and any changes made to `head` inside the function is only made to that copy.

To make it work you need to pass the arguments you change *by reference*, like

```
void append(Node *&head, Node *&last, int data)
```

Now `head` and `last` are references to the original pointer variables, and changes to the variable are made to the original variables.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `head` and `last` are passed by value, so the change of them inside the function `append` has nothing to do with the outside variables, they are independent.

You need to pass it by reference or pointer of pointer, such as:

```
void append(Node *&head, Node *&last, int data) {
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function : `append(Node *head, Node *tail, int data)`

you should pass `head` and `tail` by reference. In your approach when you are assigning `head = newNode` then it is being assigned to a local copy of `head` and not the `head` that you passed.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the address of the head and last variable and it sholud work.

```
append(&head, &last, 53);
```

and changes in the append function as below

```
void append(Node **head, Node **last, int data)
```